# python Input data in NumpyArrayIterator should have rank 4

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray

trying to test my model and i am having the error regarding the data generator input
it should be simple but i am not sure where the error is 
any advise?

Code

```
X = []


try:
  for image in test_imgs:    
      #print(image)
      img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      #print(img)
      img = cv2.resize(img, (nrows, ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

      X.append(img)

except:
  print(" ")

X_test = np.array(X)  

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

i = 0
text_labels=[]
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
for batch in test_datagen.flow(X_test, batch_size=1):
  pred=model.predict(batch)
  if pred > 0.5:
    text_labels.append(1)
  else:
    text_labels.append(0)


plt.subplot(5 / columns + 1 , columns, i + 1)
plt.title('This is a ' + text_labels[i])
imgplot = plt.imshow(batch[0])
i+=1

if i % 10 == 0:
  break


plt.show()
```

Error

```
115             raise ValueError(Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator
116                              should have rank 4. You passed an array 
117                              with shape', self.x.shape)
118         channels_axis = 3 if data_format == channels_last else 1
119         if self.x.shape[channels_axis] not in {1, 3, 4}:
```

ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (0,))

Comment: You can find a definition of rank 4f for Keras: "x: Sample data. Should have rank 4. In case of grayscale data, the channels axis should have value 1, in case of RGB data, it should have value 3, and in case of RGBA data, it should have value 4". Source: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: i am using RGB images, plus that its something wrong with loading the data itself into the X array, when i try to print it, its not printing anything which means,, nothing appended into the X array @powerPixie

Answer (score 0):

As error pointed your image shape should be 4D. n_samples, height, width and  channels.

n_samples are number of samples
height and width are the pixel value of the Image
Channels indicate RGB or Grey scale image, Where  RGB colored image value will be 3 and for Grey scale image value will be 1.